# Println in Swift with method having String Parameters

Tags: swift

```
func greetingMessage(name:String,message:String)->String{
    return "Greeting message  is \(message) for name\(name)"
}
```

The above code prints the message : "This was the message => , Greeting message  is Hello for nameJohn"

```
  println("This was the message => ",greetingMessage("John", message: "Hello"))
```

The problem here is the "," character. How do I modify this so that it doesn't appear in the output ?

Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to remove "," else everything is okie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
  println("This was the message => " + greetingMessage("John", message: "Hello"))
```

Comment: So, this is now same as Java

Comment: Yes, to combine 2 different strings in Swift, we are using **+**.

Comment: I also noticeed If I use "," then it prints the string in () parenthesis in console.

Comment: I am actually surprised that we can use "," to print something out on swift. I don't know how it has parenthesis as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
func greetingMessage(name: String, message: String) -> String {
    return "Greeting message is \(message) for name \(name)"
}

println("This was the message => " + greetingMessage("John", "Hello"))
```